# How do I compile a SPEC CPU 2006 benchmark with older glibc version?

Tags: c++, benchmarking, glibc, cpu-architecture, mars-simulator

Can somebody please help me out with making the SPEC benchmark choose glibc version 2.6.1 that is present on my system other than the default one gcc takes? primary glibc version is below

```
ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.3) 2.15
```

The Spec benchmark has a configuration file that selects a compiler by giving the path to the location of gcc. I am hoping I can make some change in this config file and point it to a different folder.

I need to do this because I want to run this benchmark on a simulated system whose kernel image has glibc 2.6.1. This simulated system is simulated using gem5 which is a cycle accurate system simulator

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to get the correct version of libglibc.so or libglibc.a and provide path to it in your linker command:

```
gcc -o a.out hello_world.o /path/to/libglib.so
```

You can get the libglibc by either downloading it on a native platform or downloading source and compiling. I have done the first one and can give more hints if needed.

Hope this helps!